# Regex match <a> tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to select a tag without custom class in my string have another a tag cannot select that's, 
String :

```
<h3 class="r"><a dir="rtl" class="sla" href="#"><span>test<span></a></h3>
<h3>test1</h3>
<h3 class="r"><a class="test" href="#">test2</a></h3>
<h3>test3</h3>
```

my Reg:

```
preg_match_all('@<h3\s*class="r">\s*<a[^<>]*href="([^<>]*)"[^<>]*>(.*)</a>\s*</h3>@siU',
        $file, $matches);
```

how i can select all in pattern  a tag without class="sla"

Comment: Sidenote: I'm not entirely sure about this, but using the `@` symbol here may not be a good idea. PHP might see that as an error suppressor. Try a different one.

Comment: Use DOM with `//a[not(@class="sla")]` xpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Boss @WiktorStribiżew is right, don't use `regex` for this kind of task, use DOM Parser instead.

Comment: Thanks all,but this reg pattern worked now for me ,and select all title between <span> tag,But I'm going to just select title As lacking <a class="sla">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regexp "negative lookahead" `<a(?![^<>]*sla)...` will discard all results with all "sla" inside "a" tag.

```
preg_match_all('@<h3\s*class="r">\s*<a(?![^<>]*sla)[^<>]*href="([^<>]*)"[^<>]*>(.*)<\/a>\s*<\/h3>@siU',
$file, $matches)
```

Also you can use more precise statement: `<a(?![^<>]*class=\"sla\")...`

Additional information about the "lookaround" expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html